# Understanding the RAM Allocation Model

Tags: ram-allocation, dawn-4.0

I'm reading articles on EOS.IO Dawn 4.0 about the RAM Allocation Model.  Articles suggest that RAM can be purchased based on speculation that the cost of RAM will go higher.  But once the cost reaches a certain point, a side-chain can be added that has it's own RAM so the cost of RAM would go down.  How can we figure out at what point will a new side-chain be established that will lower the cost of RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side-chain establishment will be determined by price inflation If at a certain point RAM exceeds average price in comparison to other chains.

I suggest you this [video by "The Awakenment"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVYg0q9E2kI) for extra information.